# Unity Web Api2 Account Controleer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to resolve Web API2 Account Controller with Unity, please suggest me how can I resolve

```
 ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
```

Here is the controller Constructor

```
 public AccountController(IDataContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            DataContext = context;
            AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
        }
```

I have resolved Unit of other two as

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, pDataContext>();
            container.RegisterInstance(typeof (UserManager<IdentityUser>),
                new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new DataContext())));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register the ISecureDataFormat as below.

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ISecureDataFormat<>), typeof(SecureDataFormat<>));
```

Or the implementation if ISecureDataFormat is non generic. You can register the type as below.

```
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat>();
```

Both above would resolve the ISecureDataFormat

[image]

Comment: this doesnt work in the latest templates. It seems SecureDataFormat does not exist, only SecureDataFormat<> and that doesnt work to resolve the injection for me. neither does the first using typeof. It also seems they provide concrete implementations for it called TicketDataFormat, but using it throws a diff error regarding ITS dependency IDataSerializer.. hmmm how does this thing wire up, geez